# When to close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

After reading and commenting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723040/make-a-copy-of-an-existing-file-and-then-allow-the-user-to-name-both-txt-files-i#comment24079539_16723040), I noticed a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724417/copy-a-txt-file#comment24082294_16724417) pop up. Looking at the writing style and users' names, I guessed that they were the same user, though I wasn't 100% positive. When the second question was first posted, there was a relative improvement over the first question: code had been provided (albeit with several easy to spot errors). It was only after looking back at the original several minutes later that I noticed he had added on code, which confirmed they were the same user.

Should I have immediately voted to close the new one or wait until the identical code was posted? If the code didn't have the obvious errors but still wasn't as ideal as a question as it could be, should I have then? I'm not sure where the line is and would like your input.

Comment: Probably he got question banned and created new account. You better flag the post by the newer account, choose Other and explain. Moderator can see IP and if the same nuke the newer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vote to close any question, but it will need at least 5 closing votes, all of them must be voted as duplicate.
You can vote to close a question as duplicate, if you think this question is already asked by some other user, or it has the same answer for some other question.
If you have power to vote, this doesn't means you need to do it by any means, as you said you are not fully sure, then please don't mark that question as duplicate.